# Class renders [object]?

Tags: typescript

I'm new to TypeScript. All i want to do in the code below is to write in the document "Hello Jonh Lennon". But when i [run this in the browser](https://jsfiddle.net/jxrvypq5/2/) (in a html page), it writes "Hello [object Object]".What am I doing wrong?

```
class Student{
    fullname: string;
    constructor(public firstName, public lastName) {
        this.fullname = firstName + '' + lastName;
    }
}

interface IPerson{
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

function say(person: IPerson){
    return "Hello " + person;   
}

var user = new Student("Jonh", "Lennon");

document.write(say(user));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[object Object] is the default behavior when javascript needs to coerce any object into a string. For `return "Hello " + person;`, javascript sees the + operator and then knows it needs person to be a string so it converts it.

What you want instead is this:

```
function say(person: IPerson){
    return "Hello " + person.fullname;   
}
```

Comment: Also, it looks like your IPerson interface is being used incorrectly here. A `Student` is not an `IPerson` because a Student only exposes a `fullname` property.